# Kal showing 2 cells for the same event

Tags: iphone, uitableview, calendar, eventkit

I have created an iphone application which utilises the Kal framework within a tab bar environment.

I create a new event using the EVENTKIT framework and it shows up to the user like this:
[image]

after you click done.. the event saves..

**BUT** when I view the Kal calendar it shows 2 entries for the same event:
[image]

**IF** I close the application, then open it again, it correctly shows the event entry in one cell..

but I don't understand why it shows the same event twice immediately after I add it..

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**
When I click the "Today" button it seems to reset/refresh the data and it works correctly..
I am currently trying to figure out how I could get it to refresh/reset every time an event is added..

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

If your code is based on the NativeCal example, there is a bug in

```
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate
```

because `[events removeAllObjects]` is called at the top of the function, and then is repopulated later in the `dispatch_async` block, the events list can contain duplicate events if the function is called again before the first call completes. I fixed this by changing the `dispatch_async` call to `dispatch_sync` to block on the call back to the main thread and to clear the events list in that call, producing the following code:

```
dispatch_async(eventStoreQueue, ^{
  NSDate *fetchProfilerStart = [NSDate date];
  NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:fromDate endDate:toDate calendars:nil];
  NSArray *matchedEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Fetched %d events in %f seconds", [matchedEvents count], -1.f * [fetchProfilerStart timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    [events removeAllObjects];
    [events addObjectsFromArray:matchedEvents];
    [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled on your solution to adding events into the Kal calendar. I was reading the header file and implementation file KalDataSource.h and KalDataSource.m and it seems that all the code to create an event should occur there. Is their anyway you could tell me what you did in adding events into your kal calendar?